# Specflow: is it possible to generate Step Definitions without Visual Studio?

Tags: .net-core, specflow

I have been working with Cucumber (Ruby and Java) and in both cases it is possible to create step definitions skeleton directly from the command line. Now I am working with SpecFlow + NetCore using dotnet-cli and VSCode.

I want to generate step definitions skeleton from the command line but all the documentation I found suggest that this feature is only available when using Visual Studio, is this correct? no command line option to generate step definitions?

Comment: I know I can create them manually but I wanted them to be created automatically just like when working on Cucumber-Ruby or Cucumber-JVM

Answer (score 2):

After reading some Specflow code and VSTest documentation I found the answer to my own question: just need to set the verbosity of the console logger to "detailed".

This means:

> dotnet test --logger:"console;verbosity=detailed"

This way the skeleton of the steps definition will be output in the console.